# How to assign values in ngIf

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-ng-if

I'm new to Angular. I'm learning directives. I'm using `pTooltip` from `primeng`. But I want to display text in pTooltip according to a condition.

Let's take example of Stack Overflow itself. You cannot upvote an answer twice. User should get msg1 if he has not upvoted that particular article otherwise he should get msg2. Where:

```
msg1="I found this article very useffeul.";
msg2="You've already upvoted this article";
```

Here is my code:

**article.component.html**

```html
<button 
  class="btn btn-success"
  *ngIf="allowUpvote ? pTooltip={{msg1}} : pTooltip={{msg2}}
  [disabled]="!allowUpvote">
  UPVOTE
</button>
```

**article.component.ts**

```js
...
allowUpvote=true;
msg1="I found this article very useffeul.";
msg2="You've already upvoted this article";
...

ngOnInit() {
  for(var i=0;i<5;i++) {
    if(this.currentLoggedInUserId==this.articleDetails.upvotersList[i]) {
      this.allowUpvote=false; //It will be set false if the user is there in the upvoters list
    }
  }
});
```

But I'm getting this error:

> Parser Error: Bindings cannot contain assignments at column 24 in [allowUpvote ? pTooltip={{msg1}} : pTooltip={{msg2}}]

Please give me some directions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this

```
[pTooltip] = "allowUpvote ? msg1 : msg2"
```

Using [], the interpretor know to read and execute code between ""

**Updated**, better explained by [Plochie](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7203873/plochie)

> When you say pTooltip="value" that means use value provided in "" as parameter for pTooltip. Here you have not binded the value from component, you have just given the constant. To have databinding you need []. Now after [], it means that bind whatever written in "" with the pTooltip and hence it will execute the code inside "" and the output for that statement then will be treated as input for pTooltip

Comment: Can you please explain this a bit more.

Comment: When you say `pTooltip="value"` that means use value provided in `""` as parameter for `pTooltip`. Here you have not binded the value from component, you have just given the constant. To have databinding you need `[]`. Now after `[]`, it means that bind whatever written in `""` with the `pTooltip` and hence it will execute the code inside `""` and the output for that statement then will be treated as input for `pTooltip`.

Answer (score 3):

it should be

`[pTooltip]="(allowUpvote) ? msg1 : msg2"`

Edit: So that means you should ditch the *ngIf, you don't need it in this case.

Comment: Oh. But what if we want it with *ngIf. I dont know. I just asking.

Comment: `ngIf` is a structural directive, used to conditionally render elements in the dom, which is different to your use case

Comment: @Tanzeel try again only this time with `[]` around pTooltip`

Comment: Tried. But now I'm getting this. `Template parse errors:
Parser Error: Got interpolation ({{}}) where expression was expected at column 0 `

Comment: This `[pTooltip] = "allowUpvote ? msg1 : msg2"` is working. AlleXys answered.

Comment: ok accept AlleXys's answer as the accepted answer then, i'll adjust my own answer